# Drag components in html

Tags: html

Is there any way for dragging some html components from a div to another div.Like visualstudio toolbox,i need to design a component container from which i have to drag the html components to another places.Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has a fairly flexible drag/drop library. It's probably one of the best-known libraries and for drag/drop work it's much easier than writing your own.

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

HTML 5 adds a level of support for drag/drop, but browser support isn't present across the board.

- http://html5demos.com/drag
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

I prefer [Twitter Bootstrap's](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) aesthetics and much lighter jQuery components to jQuery UI, but they don't currently have a drag/drop plugin. However, this is a nice demo of someone who has implemented drag/drop on top of Bootstrap. Source is available on github.

- http://bootstrap-forms.heroku.com/#

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of third-party frameworks available for drag-drop functionality. Each as certain benefits or drawbacks. The first question you should ask yourself is what platform I am working on - php, asp, etc. Then ask what browsers I want to target. jQuery will work on just about any platform and implementation can be tricky depending on your environment while a pure HTML5 will fail in older browsers. Given your target platform you can narrow the selection.

Other than jQuery, I can recommend Telerik's suite for .Net platforms, and KendoUI (jQuery with Guns), for platform agnostic integrations.